# Does AWS CloudWatch Events Rule supports any wildcards in S3 bucket/key names

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-cloudwatch

I am trying to create an event rule that is triggered by a change in a file in S3 bucket in different AWS account. Detail description is [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/events/CloudWatchEvents-CrossAccountEventDelivery.html)

So far the rule works fine with exact file names, but I need to make it work with filename prefixes. In the working example, the file name is an exact string in the non-working example the file name is a wildcard. Does CloudWatch Events Rule JSON pattern supports wildcards?

Working configuration:

```
{
  "source": ["aws.s3"],
  "account": ["1111111xxxxx"],
  "detail": {
    "eventSource": ["s3.amazonaws.com"],
    "eventName": ["PutObject"],
    "requestParameters": { "bucketName": ["mybucket"], "key": ["myfile-20180301.csv"] }
  }
}
```

Non-working configuration:

```
{
  "source": ["aws.s3"],
  "account": ["1111111xxxxx"],
  "detail": {
    "eventSource": ["s3.amazonaws.com"],
    "eventName": ["PutObject"],
    "requestParameters": { "bucketName": ["mybucket"], "key": ["myfile-*"] }
  }
}
```

Comment: I want to assign a prefix. can you tell me how to do that?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I found a fancy solution for this using [Content-based filtering](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eventbridge/latest/userguide/content-filtering-with-event-patterns.html#filtering-prefix-matching) (released in February 2020) like **prefix** for example.

So in your case, the solution should be:

```json
{
  "source": ["aws.s3"],
  "account": ["1111111xxxxx"],
  "detail": {
    "eventSource": ["s3.amazonaws.com"],
    "eventName": ["PutObject"],
    "requestParameters": {
      "bucketName": ["mybucket"],
      "key": [{ "prefix": "myfile-" }]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Provided event pattern is not valid JSON.
It's giving this error

Comment: You should try this feature on EventBridge instead of CloudWatch

Comment: Is there also a way to perform postfix matching filter? Can't find it.

Answer (score 0):

A workaround will be to have a separate bucket where you PUT/COPY the *.csv files and remove "key" parameter.
This way Cloud Watch will be triggered at any *.csv file operation on that bucket.
Another this I don't know why you are seeting the key in cloud watch event pattern if the key was already set in cloud trail.

Answer (score 0):

If you log [events of interest to Cloudwatch via CloudTrail](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/awscloudtrail/latest/userguide/send-cloudtrail-events-to-cloudwatch-logs.html), then you can use a Cloudwatch metric filter [with wildcard matching](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/logs/FilterAndPatternSyntax.html) and create a Cloudwatch Event on that filter.

Answer (score 0):

The template code gave by Marto was not working for me, however the doc led to a solution:

```
{
  "source": ["aws.s3"],
  "account": ["1111111xxxxx"],
  "detail": {
    "eventSource": ["s3.amazonaws.com"],
    "eventName": ["PutObject"],
    "requestParameters": {
      "bucketName": ["mybucket"],
      "key": [{"prefix": "myfile-*"}]
    }
  }
}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Provided event pattern is not valid JSON. It's giving this error