# Create AWS CloudWatch Event rule for S3 prefix

Tags: json, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudwatch

I wish to create an AWS CloudWatch Event rule for S3 create events, in a specific bucket and prefix. Since CloudWatch does not support wildcards, I am instead trying to give the prefix explicitly as in the following example:
[Does AWS CloudWatch Events Rule supports any wildcards in S3 bucket/key names](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49435580/does-aws-cloudwatch-events-rule-supports-any-wildcards-in-s3-bucket-key-names)

(for obfuscation I provide the bucket and prefix names here as `my-data-bucket` and `my-data-prefix/`)

My JSON rule:

```
{
  "source": [
    "aws.s3"
  ],
  "detail-type": [
    "AWS API Call via CloudTrail"
  ],
  "detail": {
    "eventSource": [
      "s3.amazonaws.com"
    ],
    "eventName": [
      "PutObject",
      "CompleteMultipartUpload"
    ],
    "requestParameters": {
      "bucketName": [
        "my-data-bucket"
      ],
      "key": [{ "prefix": "my-data-prefix/" }]
    }
  }
}
```

Yields the error:

```
Event pattern contains invalid element (can only be Strings enclosed in quotes, numbers, and the unquoted keywords true, false, and null)
```

This might be that the curly braces are not allowed for the `key` request parameter, but how can you create a rule to listen to just a specific prefix, without being allowed wildcards?
(and preferably without having to customize the CloudTrail trail as in [Cloudwatch event rule listen to s3 bucket with specific keypath](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53776856/cloudwatch-event-rule-listen-to-s3-bucket-with-specific-keypath))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your event is invalid in CloudWatch Events (CWE) rule, but should be fine for CWE replacement, i.e. **AWS EventBridge** (EB). Thus I would recommend using EB for that event.

EB is basically a new version of CWE, so you can do same thing.